# IPV4 address changes so it's hard to host a server. How do I change this?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, ipv4

I have a laptop and I am hosting a game server at the moment at home. Now, my problem is while port forwarding I have to add in my IPv4 address while port forwarding. My laptop is connected with WiFi and my IPv4 address is changing every time I boot my laptop. Is there anyway to just kind of **prefer** a IPv4 address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are having problems with your router changing the IP address its giving your laptop.  Many routers have a feature called "Static DHCP Leases" or "Address Reservations".  This allows you to enter your MAC address and assign a specific IP address to always assign that MAC.

If your router doesn't support that, you can still choose an IP address outside the range of the addresses assigned by the DHCP server and set it up statically.

### Update

For your specific router (TL-WR841N) you can setup an Address Reservation using the "DHCP" menu item in your router's configuration.  You can find your MAC address from the "DHCP Clients List."

For the "Reserved IP Address" field, select an IP that is on the same subnet that the DHCP server is using, but outside the range being handed out by the DHCP server.  For example, if the the DHCP server is using `192.168.1.100` to `192.168.1.199`, select and address such as `192.168.1.50`.

Comment: Euhm ok so sorry but can you explain in steps how to get 1 IPV4 address?

Comment: What kind of router do you have?  Most modern routers will do do static leases.

Comment: TP-Link WR841N (TL-WR841N)

Comment: @Loko, I've updated my answer for your specific router.

Comment: You are a genius, a god!

Answer (score -1):

You can't choose a particular IP address. Your ISP asssins you a new IP address every time you join and you can't change this.

What you can do is ask your ISP for a Static address, this way your address will always remain the same.

Comment: If they won't budge on assigning you a static address, you can ask for them to change the _lease_ time for the address given to you. Maybe they'll at least give you the lease time to keep an address for a longer period of time.

Comment: Given that he's port-forwarding on his router, it sounds like the problem is with his internal LAN IP address rather than his publicly facing IP address.

Answer (score -1):

Here are two choices:

- You can request a static IP address from you ISP.  Note that most ISPs (if not all) will charge more for providing a static IP address
- You can use a [dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service that will dynamically update DNS when your IP changes.  Some examples of this service are:  [NoIP](http://www.noip.com/free), [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/), and [FreeDNS](http://freedns.afraid.org/)

Comment: Given that he's port-forwarding on his router, it sounds like the problem is with his internal LAN IP address rather than his publicly facing IP address.